# How can I get the background image show to the bottom when zoomed out?

Tags: css

This website http://www.ideaseat.com/TRANSFER/MosaicFIsite/ has a huge background image. It's showing all of it vertically when I zoom out but not horizontally. I need the background image to go all the way to the bottom without setting the height. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your CSS, specify this for your `body` element:

```
body {
    background-image: url("assets/main_bg.jpg");
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
}
```